# Amplifier Circuit as a Signal Adder

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, signal, adder

Consider two input signals, v1(t) and v2(t). Each has a source resistance of 10 kΩ. We require the output signal to be the weighted sum of the two inputs,

vo(t) = 15v1(t) + 20v2(t),

delivered to a RL = 10 kΩ load. Resistors of arbitrary resistance; and voltage amplifiers with Ri = 100 kΩ, Ro = 1 kΩ, and Avo = 10 V/V are available. Design a circuit to meet the design requirements, within the constraints:

• The complete circuit uses the minimum number of amplifier stages.

I am unsure how to individually amplify each input voltage to meet the requirements of the equation.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Summing_amplifier

Answer (score 0):

I will not give the solution *(because it seems a homework question to me)*, but I'll try to show a path:

- If the two sources (v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub>) having non-zero output impedances (R<sub>o1</sub> and R<sub>o2</sub>, respectively) are connected in parallel, the output voltage (v<sub>o</sub>) will be
  $$
  \mathrm{v_o=\frac{(v_1\cdot R_{o2})(v_2\cdot R_{o1})}{(R_{o1}+R_{o2})}}
  $$

and the output impedance will be
$$
\mathrm{R_{o}=R_{o1} || R_{o2}}
$$

- If a voltage source having a non-zero output impedance (r<sub>o</sub>) is connected to the input of an amplifier having a finite input impedance (R<sub>i</sub>),  the input voltage seen by the amplifier will be divided according the voltage divider rule.

I think you can now go from here.